# How to force the underlying form object to overtake the parent entity for its relation?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have one master entity and second one.

Lets say you have a map and the map has some points with coordinates.

I want be able to add dynamicaly new records for points so I've choosen the collection type of form type.

I have also the correct form type for the second entity. Everything is OK, except that the new added points are not persisted with the master entity. How can I tell the form to overtake the parent entity and set to the appropriate setter?

```
$builder->add('routePoints', 'collection', ['required' => false,'label' => '','attr'=>['class'=>'route-point'],'by_reference'=> true, 'type' => new MapCoordinateAdminType(), 'allow_add' => true, 'delete_empty' => true, 'allow_delete' => true, 'translation_domain' => 'maps']);
```

Master Entity

```
/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ADN\CustomBundle\Entity\MapCoordinate", cascade={"persist","remove"}, mappedBy="map")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE",name="route_points",nullable=true, referencedColumnName="map")
 */
protected $routePoints;
```

Points Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy="routePoints", targetEntity="ADN\CustomBundle\Entity\CycleMap")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="map",referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $map;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second entity instances are not persisted because they belong to the inverse side of the bidirectional relationship. You can find out more about this on the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts).

In order to solve your problem, you need to update the owning side as well. To do this, a one-line change is required in your master entity:

```
<?php
/** Master entity */
use ADN\CustomBundle\Entity\MapCoordinate;

class CycleMap
{
    // ...

    public function addRoutePoint(MapCoordinate $routePoint)
    {
         // The magical line
         $routePoint->setMap($this);

         $this->routePoints[] = $routePoint;

         return $this;
    }
}
```